# How can I remove or subset certain context in a text?

Tags: r, text

Here is my data

```
data<- "line1\nline2\n\n\n\n\n         VICTIMS OF GUN VIOLENCE TO HOLD GUN TRAFFICKERS LIABLE\n\n  line3"
```

I want the text between the five consecutive "\n" and the two consecutive "\n" :

"VICTIMS OF GUN VIOLENCE TO HOLD GUN TRAFFICKERS LIABLE"

I tried

```
text-<str_split(data,"\n") 
str_subset(text,".*\n{5}\\s*(.*)\\s*\n{2}.*")
```

I get:
Warning message:
In stri_subset_regex(string, pattern, omit_na = TRUE, negate = negate,  :
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `sub` to capture the text between 5 `'\n'` and 2 `'\n'`.

```
sub('.*\n{5}\\s*(.*)\\s*\n{2}.*', '\\1', data)
#[1] "VICTIMS OF GUN VIOLENCE TO HOLD GUN TRAFFICKERS LIABLE"
```

Comment: It works. But when I apply it to my real data, I get "VICTIMS OF GUN VIOLENCE TO HOLD GUN TRAFFICKERS LIABLE\n\n  (Mr. CASTEN of Illinois ...".  I use "line3" to represent the text after the 2"\n" in my question. I do not understand the argument: use '\\1' to replace '.*\n{5}\\s*(.*)\\s*\n{2}.*'  ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is back reference to return the capture group mentioned in `(.*)`. I think in your real data there is another instance which has 2 `\n`. Try `sub('.*\n{5}\\s*(.*?)\\s*\n{2}.*', '\\1', data)` making the capture group non-greedy with `.*?`.

Comment: works perfect now! still curious what's wrong with my str_split and str_subset. But your method is way more parsimonious. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `str_subset` is the right function here. See some examples how it is used in `?str_subset`. It returns entire string if the pattern is matched. Here you only want to return part of the string and not the entire string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you recommend me a book or video to learn text mining in R please?

Comment: Have you read https://www.tidytextmining.com/  ? Seems like a good resource.